# SoftPhone and linux

Tags: sip, telephony

We are thinking about writing a softphone app. It would basically be a component of a system that has calls queued up from a database. It would interface with a LINUX server which has Asterisk installed.
My first question is

> Whether we should write the softphone at all or just buy one?

Secondly, if we do,

> what base libraries should be use?

I see SIP Sorcery on CodePlex. More than anything, I am looking for a sense of direction here. Any comments or recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would depend on the capabilities you have in your team and the place you see your core value and the essence of the service you provide.

In most cases, I'd guess that you don't really care about SIP or doing anything fancy with it that require access to its low level. In such a case, I'd recommend getting a ready-made softphone - either a commercial one or an open source one. I'd go for a commercial one, as it will give you the peace of mind as to its stability and assistance with bug fixing and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, one of the many open source softphones are likely to fit your needs, and allow slight modifications as needed. Under most open source licenses there is no obligation to distribute your code as long as you only use it internally (do not distribute the binary.)

Trying to guess what you are trying to do, it sounds like a call center like scenario, so one of the many call queue implementations out there might fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I had to write an own softphone and I found a great guide how to achieve it. In the guide there are 10 steps provided for having an own softphone ([voip-sip-sdk.com](http://voip-sip-sdk.com/) on page 272)

I found it useful and maybe you will find it as well.